# I get problems regarding mathematical operations using an array php

Tags: php, math, floating-point-precision

I do mathematical calculations using two arrays like this

$d_positif

```
array(3) { [0]=> float(2.7742631687417) [1]=> float(2.5949809043991) [2]=> float(3.0174025996932) }
```

$d_negatif

```
array(3) { [0]=> float(2.7259998526469) [1]=> float(3.4826656582587) [2]=> float(3.2284968891602) }
```

and i have formula

```
$count = count($d_positif);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $v[$i] = $d_positif[$i] / ($d_negatif[$i] + $d_positif[$i]);
    }
```

V1 = 2.7742631687417 / (2.7742631687417 + 2.7259998526469)

V2 = 2.5949809043991 / (2.5949809043991 + 3.4826656582587)

V3 = 3.0174025996932 / (3.0174025996932 + 3.2284968891602)

I should get a result like this

```
array(3) { [0]=> float(0,495612636) [1]=> float(0,573028659) [2]=> float(0,51689863) }
```

but the output of mathematical operations like this

```
array(3) { [0]=> float(0.50438736437759) [1]=> float(0.42697134123315) [2]=> float(0.48310136995931) }
```

anyone can help me why it can be like that?

Comment: I typed your first calculation ( 2.7742631687417 / (2.7742631687417 + 2.7259998526469) ) into the windows calculator and I get exactly the result you are getting (0,50438736437758711142967896416502) , but not expecting. Tells me you might be wrong with your expected result. Why are you expecting YOUR results? Is it from some previous calculation?

Comment: Every PHP version on this planet calculates the results you get, not the results you expect: http://3v4l.org/sbc8d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are expecting is actually the result of

```
$v[$i] = $d_negatif[$i] / ($d_negatif[$i] + $d_positif[$i]);
```

not

```
$v[$i] = $d_positif[$i] / ($d_negatif[$i] + $d_positif[$i]);
```